# How to handle loops and lines in a vscode debugging extension?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

A loop looks like this:

```
<ForLoop variable="i" from="1" to="3">

        <Console.Log
                     message="Loop {i} A" />

        <Console.Log message="Loop {i} B" />
</ForLoop>
```

If I start to debugging step by step, each line  is "executed" once and not working in a loop. I did not find anything to handle loops, did I miss it?
And this expression "`<Console.Log message="Loop {i} A" />`" is two times in focus.
Do I have to define something in the package.json at languages?
Or can I set the line with the debug-adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position shown as the current point of execution is purely determined by your call stack. Whatever you return in your `stackTraceRequest` implemention directly determines all the execution "positions" in your entire call stack (even if you select other stack frames).